# ios ad-hoc profile ignored when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an ad-hoc distribution profile. I am trying to load the app to the app store for beta testing only. However, when I run the xcode (using xcode 7) archive it ignores the build settings and switches to the non-ad-hoc distribution profile.

I have read many threads and I am still not clear if

1. I should care that it is doing that
2. If I should care then why is it happening? The ad-hoc profile is active.

Comment: Make sure you are using right ad-hoc profile and certificate in Build Settings of the target. Do you have a valid certificated installed?

Comment: Yes I do. This is the actual issue I have: when archiving, xcode uses the xc dist profile. And I cannot change it. If after archiving I opt to export (I.e IPA file only), it allows me to select the ad-hoc profile. However, I cannot submit an ipa file only to iTunes connect. At least not through xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're uploading to the AppStore, you need to use **AppStore distribution provisioning profile**. You can still use your ad-hoc profile when exporting for ad-hoc deployment. (**TestFlight** is an integral part of the AppStore now, and is not considered ad-hoc distribution platform anymore...)

From [Test Flight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html):

> You should take the following steps to set up prerelease versions of
>   your app for testing in iTunes Connect:
>
> ...
>
> Generate a new
>   **App Store Distribution profile** containing the beta entitlement to
>   distribute builds via TestFlight.
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've spent a lot of time on this but I did not manage to find this in apple docs. Can you point me to the documentation? I would like to know if I missed anything else...

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I actually manage to upload to itunes connect and deploy via testflight to one user. What is still confusing to me in the docs (not that it matters because I got it to work) is the statement `Distribution profile containing the beta entitlement`. It does not actually say that the Beta entitlement is now automatically included and it does not clearly states that one does not need an Ad-Hoc certificate anymore...again, being picky here. Thanks again!